# Can we infect with "bad" genes other organisms?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, virus

We know that some organism's DNA stay with human for life ([Herpes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_labialis)) and we also can, i think, design such "gene" that can interact with human's DNA-polymerase very intensive.

If we attached this gene to herpes virus and after that it infected human, would our "artificial gene" be produced and replicated by human DNA-polymerase and how it can affect infected human? Is it possible? What are difficulties we can face?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to rephrase your question as "can virus mediated lateral gene transfer happen in higher eukaryotes/animals". That would be a good question. Avoid asking open ended questions like "what difficulties can we face".

Answer (score 1):

It is common in biology to use a virus to deliver new genetic information to a cell. Such a virus is called a viral vector. Retroviruses can be used to enable the viral DNA to be incorporated into the cell's genome. Usually viral genes are removed, making the virus unable to replicate once the cell is infected [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK19423/). Using viral vectors *in vivo* to "correct" disease-causing genetic mutations is a commonly studied aspect to gene therapy [2](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/therapy/procedures).

For obvious reasons, people for years have been considering how genetic engineering and gene therapy may be used as a bioterrorism weapon, and ways to ensure our safety if it is used as a bioweapon [3](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2013/03/genetically-engineered-bioweapons-a-new-breed-of-weapons-for-modern-warfare/#.V1hdeJMrKN8).

[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK19423/) - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK19423/

[2](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/therapy/procedures) - [https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/therapy/procedures](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2013/03/genetically-engineered-bioweapons-a-new-breed-of-weapons-for-modern-warfare/#.V1hdeJMrKN8)

[3](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2013/03/genetically-engineered-bioweapons-a-new-breed-of-weapons-for-modern-warfare/#.V1hdeJMrKN8) - [http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2013/03/genetically-engineered-bioweapons-a-new-breed-of-weapons-for-modern-warfare/#.V1hdeJMrKN8](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/therapy/procedures)